# Solr distributed search test case: Cannot resolve org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm trying to test a custom distributed Solr component that I've developed. In order to do so I extend Solr's `BaseDistributedSearchTestCase` class. The problem is that `BaseDistributedSearchTestCase` imports `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder` and the `eclipse` symbol cannot be resolved. Where in the Solr distribution do I find the jar I should add to my dependencies in order to resolve the `eclipse` symbol?